# VUE error : Discarded invalid param(s) "recordIds", "datasources" when navigating

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

in Vue i am facing an issue while passing params from one route to another.
This with what my target route looks like :

```
{
   path: '/record-modification',
   name: 'recordModification',
   component: recordModification,
   meta: { needAuthentication: true, needCaseId: true }
}
```

This is how i am pushing data to route :

```
this.$router.push({
     name: 'recordModification',
     params: {
         recordIds,
         datasources
     }
});
```

But on target page when i tried to access  **this.$route.params** i am getting an empty object. Any idea what wrong am i doing here ?

Comment: I have just come across the same issue. Read this: https://github.com/vuejs/router/blob/main/packages/router/CHANGELOG.md#414-2022-08-22

Comment: Thanks @mackesmilian I have checked this documentation already. Shall i use pinia ? I tried with state but still getting same result?

Comment: I use Pinia, yes.

Answer (score 2):

change params to query:

```js
this.$router.push({
     name: 'recordModification',
     query: {
         recordIds,
         datasources
     }
});
```

and change it when you call the params in 'recordModification' too:

```
 $route.query.recordIds
```